# IDE (CLion) can't resolve C++ Template type

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have a template class:

```
template<class _I2CApi>
class Pca9538 {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<board::I2CApi, _I2CApi>::value, "_I2CApi must inherit from I2CApi");

    typedef _I2CApi I2CApi;
```

And an implementation:

```
template<class _I2CApi>
uint8_t Pca9538<_I2CApi>::interaction(bool isRead, uint8_t cmd, uint8_t data) {
    _I2CApi i2c; // No Autocompletion for board::I2CApi fields
```

Can I somehow better describe that `_I2CApi` is of type `board::I2CApi`.

Comment: Note that all names beginning with underscore + capital letter are reserved for the implementation. Using such identifiers is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MaxLanghof to be pedantic, *declaring* such identifiers (which is what Tarion did) has undefined behaviour. Using implementation defined identifiers is well, implementation defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the members through the base class:

```
board::I2CApi& api = i2c;
```

Your IDE should be able to autocomplete members of `board::I2CApi` in this case.

Comment: Okay the trick is to have a reference to the base class. I might just add it as member then.